# Failing to load font in SFML

Tags: c, cmake, fonts, sfml, lib

## Problem description

I'm trying to write some text to the screen, but it feels like no matter what I do i always get:

```
Failed to load font "../assets/Font.ttf" (failed to create the font face)
```

A very simple example of the code.

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("../assets/Font.ttf");
    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML works!");
    sf::Text text("Hello World", font, 50);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
        window.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm building using `Cmake` and I expect that the problem lies in my `CMakeLists` files. I have one main and a sub-directory like: (Also very simple)

```
#Main

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Sorting_Visualization)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

```
# Sub Directory

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

File structure:

```
.
├── assets
│   └── Font.ttf
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

## What I've tried

I read that similar problems occurred when people using Visual Studio linked release libs to their debug builds. There was suggested to link with ex. `sfml-graphics-d` for debug libs. However this doesn't seem to work for me and using `dpkg libsfml-dev` I don't see any files matching `sfml-graphics-d`. **Should I maybe install these in some way?**. Or is that some Visual Studio specific issue?

Further I think I was missing the `Freetype` dependecy at the time of installing `SFML` however running `ldd` on my `sfml-graphics.so` file it seem that freetype is found.

```
libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f26fdca0000)
```

Lastly I was thinking that maybe the font I'm using is simply not compatible. But surely any true type font should be possible to use. Here is a [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) the font.

## To summarize

I think I've read nearly everything there is online and I'm still completely stumped. The only thing left is my linking in Cmake which I found no clear resources on and I'm pretty new to working with libs. Some guidence would be greatly appreciated on this : )

Comment: One potential problem is that the working directory of the program isn't where you expect so the relative directory isn't valid. Try using an absolute path to eliminate that as an issue. If it still doesn't load with the absolute path you know it's an issue somewhere in the code.

Comment: Good suggestion, @RetiredNinja! I tried that just now but to no luck : (

Comment: Also tried with different font `Arial`, which also didn't work. But I suppose then It's diffidently Cmake or some of my installs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I solved the problem and it was apparently the order in which I was finding the packages and linking them. I also have to always `make all`

This is working!

```
set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS REQUIRED audio graphics )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} sfml-audio sfml-graphics)
```